# mypy - How to mark line as unreachable

Tags: python, mypy

I've got a function of the form:

```py
def get_new_file(prefix: str) -> pathlib.Path:
    for i in itertools.count(0):
        p = pathlib.Path(f'{prefix}_{i}')
        if not p.is_file():
            return p
    # This line is unreachable.
```

mypy understandably complains that the function is missing a return statement.  Is there a way to mark a line so as to inform mypy that the line should be considered unreachable?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This was raised as [an issue](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/5992). The recommended solution is `assert False`.

```py
def get_new_file(prefix: str) -> pathlib.Path:
    for i in itertools.count(0):
        p = pathlib.Path(f'{prefix}_{i}')
        if not p.is_file():
            return p
    assert False
```

Answer (score 3):

Once again this is a typical issue where keeping things simple should apply. mypy obviously does not know where the loops ends, so it's warning you about it in advance as the function's end-of-line statement does not have a `return` statement.

A simple approach is to break the loop and return the last value of the `pathlib.Path` which was last set. Here is an example.

```py
def get_new_file(prefix: str) -> pathlib.Path:
    p : Optional[pathlib.Path] = None 
    for i in itertools.count(0):
        p = pathlib.Path(f'{prefix}_{i}')
        if not p.is_file():
            break
        
    return p
```

If you restructure the above code snippet, mypy will not raise the errors again.

Answer (score 2):

Mypy is not wrong, you should not mark that line as unreachable but raise an error, even if you are sure that you won't ever hit that line it's a good coding practice and you can save yourself some time debugging later on

```
def get_new_file(prefix: str) -> pathlib.Path:
    for i in itertools.count(0):
        p = pathlib.Path(f'{prefix}_{i}')
        if not p.is_file():
            return p
    raise Exception # pick a meaningful exception
```

Comment: Doesn't `assert False` raise such an assertion?

Comment: No, asserts are no-OP and they are only run on debug mode.

Comment: Fair point.  However, in such a case as this where the line is quite obviously unreachable, I'm happy with merely satisfying mypy.

Comment: you can also just use a while loop, but it's a bit more ugly I guess